# Git alias for fast commit with optional text

Tags: git, bash, shell, alias, commit

This is my git alias configuration in the CONFIG file

```
[alias]
    cm = "!git add .;git commit -m 'commit';git push origin master"
```

Instead to use 'commit' for every commit, I would like to specify it with something like:

```
git cm --'my commit text'
```

or

```
git cm 'commit text'
```

Even better, the argument should be optional, so that I can simply type `git cm` to just make a commit with the text *'commit'*, but actually this is not a priority

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're going to use positional parameters, I would suggest using a function:

```
cm = "!f() { git add .; git commit -m \"${1:-commit}\"; git push origin master; }; f"
```

The `!` instructs git to run the command in a subshell. A function `f` is defined, which uses either the message provided as the first argument or a default of `commit`. The function is then called.

Use it like `git cm "your message here"` or just `git cm` to use the default.